# Testcafe not generating report with large amount of screenshot

Tags: testcafe

I am producing more than 300mb of report file. Our testcases has large amount of screenshots. Testcafe also not generating any error. Its just producing empty report file sometime. could you guide me what possible steps I have do to solve this issue??. Do I have to increase memory?? how should I increase memory with testcafe. I didn't found any information in testcafe document about memory parameter.

Comment: Hi,

To determine the cause of this issue, we need to reproduce and research it locally. Please create a GitHub issue: [Bug Report](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml) and share all details about your usage scenario. Please also share the reporter you are using. A simple runnable project would also be helpful.